# playback a speech file and record it automatically: the record application doesn't generate any file

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk

I have two asterisk servers, the first is a call initiator and the second is a call receiver. What I want is that a call initiated by the first gets recorded automatically in the second.

The configuration of the first server is as follows:

**sip.conf**

```
[general]  
register => AS2AS1:welcome@192.168.1.67 
[AS1AS2] 
type=friend 
disallow=all 
allow=iLBC 
secret=welcome 
host=dynamic 
context=startcall 
username=AS2AS1 
dtmfmode=rfc2833 
qualify=1000
```

**extensions.conf**

```
[startcall] 
exten => 333,1,Playback(sa11)
```

and the configuration of the second server is as follows

**sip.conf**

```
[general] 
register => AS1AS2:welcome@192.168.1.66 
[AS2AS1] 
disallow=all 
allow=iLBC 
type=friend 
secret=welcome 
host=dynamic 
username=AS1AS2 
context=recordcall 
dtmfmode=rfc2833 
qualify=1000
```

**extensions.conf**

```
[recordcall] 
exten => 333,1,Answer() 
exten => 333,2,Set(curtime=$(STRFTIME(,,%s)}) 
exten => 333,3,Record(/home/basma/recorded/${curtime}.wav) 
exten => 333,4,Hangup()
```

the call file(in the call initiator server):

```
Channel:SIP/AS1AS2/333
Context:startcall
Extension:333
```

but when the call is completed i find nothing in the recorded directory!

Answer (score 0):

Can be anything, including "asterisk not able call out at all"

To see more info, connect to asterisk using

```
asterisk -r
core set verbose 10
```

and see output while calling.

But note, you call file is incorrect. Have be Priority.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

Comment: thank you,
 I added `Priority:1` to the callfile
that's what i get in the receiver call server
`== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [333@recordcall:1] Answer("SIP/AS2AS1-00000000", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [333@recordcall:2] Set("SIP/AS2AS1-00000000", "curtime=$(STRFTIME(,,%s)}") in new stack
    -- Executing [333@recordcall:3] Record("SIP/AS2AS1-00000000", "/home/basma/recorded/$(STRFTIME(,,%s)}.wav") in new stack
    -- <SIP/AS2AS1-00000000> Playing 'beep.gsm' (language 'en')
  == Spawn extension (recordcall, 333, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/AS2AS1-00000000'`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding any action after `Record()` for example `Playback(hello-world)` or `Wait(10)`

```
[recordcall] 
exten => 333,1,Answer() 
exten => 333,n,Set(curtime=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%s)}) 
exten => 333,n,Record(/home/basma/recorded/${curtime}.wav) 
exten => 333,n,Playback(hello-world) 
exten => 333,n,Hangup()
```

The `beep` you hear from Record application, but after that `Hangup` is called and call is ended.

Also make sure asterisk or user that runs `*` has write permissions to `/home/basma/recorded/`
check which user runs `*` with

```
ps aux | grep asterisk
```

and then

```
chown -R <user>:<user> /home/basma/recorded/
```

Comment: thank you, i added an action after `Record` exactly as you told me but it didn't execute it, it stopped at `exten => 333,n,Record(/home/basma/recorded/${curtime}.wav)` and i get `Spawn extension (recordcall, 333, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/AS2AS1-00000012'` and in the initiator server i get `Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/AS1AS2-00000007' status is 'UNKNOWN'`
Asterisk has write permissions to `/home/basma/recorded/`

Comment: I edited `exten => 333,n,Set(curtime=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%s)})` don't know if it was syntax or copy/paste error but you need `${` not `$(`, + add ${EPOCH} and see in log how is variable ${curtime} set, is it getting good value?

Comment: i corrected it and the variable ${curtime} is getting good value but nothing else has changed, i still get the same errors mentioned above.

Comment: can you post me the log, how does Record line looks like in full log or cli, or last 3 lines

Comment: `== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [333@recordcall:1] Answer("SIP/AS2AS1-00000001", "") in new stack 
    -- Executing [333@recordcall:2] Set("SIP/AS2AS1-00000001", "curtime=1373529315") in new stack
    -- Executing [333@recordcall:3] Record("SIP/AS2AS1-00000001", "/home/basma/recorded/1373529315.wav") in new stack
    -- <SIP/AS2AS1-00000001> Playing 'beep.gsm' (language 'en                  �')
  == Spawn extension (recordcall, 333, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/AS2AS1-00000001'`

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing `beep.gsm` file from `/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/` or `/usr/share/asterisk/sounds/en`, make sure that it is there and that it is not zero size. If it's not there copy it from somewhere or download sounds again. But that would trigger `file.c:663 ast_openstream_full: File beep does not exist in any format`

Comment: i verified right now, `beep.gsm` exists in `/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/` and its size is 726 bytes

Comment: `Playing 'beep.gsm' (language 'en �')` what is that `?` and how did it got there, what AST version are you running?

Comment: i'm running asterisk 11.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem and the recorded file is generated after some modifications in extensions.conf in both initiator and receiver servers.

In the **initiator** server **extensions.conf** is as follows:

```
[startcall]
exten => 333,1,Wait(1)
exten => 333,n,Playback(sa11)
exten => 333,n,WaitExten(10)
```

And in the **receiver** server **extensions.conf** is:

```
[recordcall]
exten => 333,1,Answer()
exten => 333,n,Set(curtime=${STRFTIME(,,%s)})
exten => 333,n,Record(/home/basma/recorded/${curtime}.wav,0,5)
exten => 333,n,Wait(3)
exten => 333,n, Hangup()
```